# Dynamic React Router with Tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have a page with a table, where you click on a `<tr>` and the user is redirected to another page, like this:

```
// parent component
<tr onClick={() => this.props.history.push(`users/${id}`)}>
```

At the new page called users, there are two tabs which also redirect to other pages:

```
// users page receives the id from the parent 
// component with this.props.history.push()
<Tab label='Users' key='users'>
    <div>users page content</div>
</Tab>

// This page must also receive the id from parent component. 
// The structure is similar to users page.
<Tab label='Info' key='info'>
    <Redirect to={'/info/:id'} />
</Tab>
```

So, I need to pass the id from the parent page to [info page/tab 2] and redirect from [info page/tab 2] to [users/tab 1] at will with the id from parent, something like this:

```
[tab 1]: users/12345
[tab 2]: info/12345
```

How can I achieve this result? 
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you define your Routes like

```
/users/:userId
/info/:userId
```

You can read the userID from params and use that to navigate between pages

```
<Tab label='Info' key='info'>
    <Redirect to={`/info/${this.match.params.userId}`} />
</Tab>
```

Comment: I tried something like that, but the url appears something like this idk why: `info/:id12345`. And then when I go from `[info tab]` to `[users tab]`, the url looks like this `users/:id:id12345`

Comment: You might be writing `<Redirect to={'/info/:id'} />` wherein you need to write `<Redirect to={\`/info/${this.match.params.id}\`} />`

Comment: It's like this now: `<Redirect to={${routes.INFO}${this.props.match.params.id}} />`, where routes.INFO is `/info/:id`

Comment: If I remove the `:id` from `/info/`, the url looks `/info/12345`, but I can't see the content of Info page.

Comment: `export const USERS = '/users/:id'
export const INFO = '/info/'
export const PARENT = '/parent'`

Comment: I meant, how you configured your Route config

Comment: `<ProtectedRoute component={ParentPage} exact path={routes.PARENT} />
            <ProtectedRoute component={UserPage} exact path={routes.USERS} />
            <ProtectedRoute component={InfoPage} exact path={routes.INFO}  />`

Comment: Changing INFO to `export const INFO = '/info/:id'` would be work provider you do not use routes.INFO in redirect. Instead for redirect write `<Redirect to=\`/info/${this.props.match.params.id}\`} />`

Comment: It's like I said before, I already tried your solution and this link happened : `info/:id12345`. And you are right, it should work, but something is off :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188908/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-rcohen).